# Dynamic Image rendering is slow

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, cloudpage

My order email contains images, so each image resides in another system which is a different URL, Now if I wanted to change the dimensions of the image, I need to edit the URL itself where it contains the width and height parameters, then accordingly it gives the modified image. this would take some time to render.

As I display ordered images dynamically in the email, Once I receive the email, it actually takes time to render the images from the inbox. so is there any way to make these images render instantaneously? like through cloud page if I hit those URLs dynamically and then send happens will render images quickly through some cache. any idea or suggestions for this?

Comment: Are you saying it is taking extra time at send queue, reducing throughput or that once the email arrives in the inbox and you open it, it takes a while for the image to load?

Comment: Hi Gortonington, Second part is right, Once it arrives in the inbox, Images take while to load

Comment: Don’t think it’s a marketing cloud issue, but you could do a test with two emails, in one include the image hosted externally and in the second one the same image hosted in sfmc and see if there is any difference https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/01/testing-email-load-download-speed/

Comment: Yes, its not with MC. Looking for any input on preloading those images through cloud page or somewhere, so that the image can load quickly by pulling it from preloaded cache.

Comment: Don’t think that’s possible